# Why is not good to use associative arrays instead of attributes in a class?

Tags: php, class, object, attributes

Can someone explain me why when I see a php class there are always a lot of attributes? Wouldn't be better use an associative array?

For example:

```
class Stundent {
     public $id;
     public $name;
     public $mail;
}
```

it wouldn't be the same something like this:

```
class Stundent {

 public $state= {id=>$id,name=>$name,mail=>$mail}

}
```

In this case, I'll have more flexibility. I could add new attributes without having to touch  my code again.

Just wondering what I am missing :D

Answer (score 1):

Visibility. You cannot set them as private or protected, unless whole group is same type.

Also, you cannot use setters and getters (or you have to make not nice hacks, such as pass index).

And in my opinion, such design 'technique' would be much harder to extend or maintain.